# Error in Redirecting to asp.net page when clicking second time on a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When i am clicking on a link on my asp.net page first time it getting redirected correctly to that page but when second time i am clicking on link it is appending different URL to the existing URL and error page is displayed saying resource is not found.
do anybody knows what could be the problem.
I am using href links to navigate through pages with jquery as well in my asp.net master page.

Comment: Some code will be appreciated.

Comment: <a href="javascript:" onclick="showsubmenu(this)">Employee</a>
              <div class="submenu_pane submenu_pane2">
 <a href="Masters/Employee/EmployeeGroupsView.aspx">EmployeeGroups</a>
</div>

Comment: Share that code where you redirect to webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above snippet is: absolute path... !!!

Make sure you use"/" before the URL:

```
<a href="/Masters/Employee/EmployeeGroupsView.aspx">EmployeeGroups</a>
```

Comment: For next click on the hyperlink it is appending the path from Masters/Employee/Masters/Employee..../example.aspx
i.e for second time it is appending the same folder

Comment: instead of html Hyperlinks i need to use asp.net hyperlink, it will take care of that absolute and relative path.this is a good solution.